# Forwarding custom page rule for known ip adresses

Tags: iptables, apache-2.4, ubuntu-12.04, php5, ip-routing

I want to add some ip adresses to a blacklist, and i want to show these ip addresses in blacklist a custom web page that includes a "you are in blacklist" message on body.

How can i do this?

I have ubuntu server and apache. 
I tried to add rule to ip tables but it only drops connection.
I do not want to drop connection i want to route it to a custom .html . 
Thanks.

Comment: Define *"show"*, *"them"* and the processs of *staring*. Until done you can print a banner **"you are in a blacklist"**, stick it to a chassis of your server - whenever *they* will look at it, *they* will see your message.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to HTTP protocol and remote web-clients, like browsers, then, to display a warning page to a set of such clients, basing on their IP address information, you can use `mod_rewrite` to rewrite the `DocumentRoot` of a given *vhost* (the one that you want to protect) to some path, say `/blacklisted.html`.

For example, consider the following approach:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^12\.34\.56\.78$
RewriteRule ^/.* /blacklisted.html
```

And `/blacklisted.html` is supposed to contain scary warnings and threats.